# disable child view touches when parent disabled

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view, touch-event, user-experience

I am creating a clickable custom view to replace `android.widget.Switch`(`Switch`), using `onDraw` instead of additional `Drawable`. When I use `Switch` previously, if parent is disabled, the `Switch` is also not clickable, but when I migrated to my custom view, it's still clickable when parent disabled. How can I know if I should disable/ignore clicks?

---

custom view parent enabled
[image: custom view parent enabled]

custom view parent disabled (still clickable!)
[image: custom view parent disabled]

`Switch` parent disabled (not clickable)
[image: android.widget.Switch parent disabled]

---

my code like...

```java
public class MySwitch extends View {

  public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (isClickable() && isEnabled()) {
      //do something
    }
  }

  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //draw track and thumb
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try validating parent as a `ViewGroup` as following.

```java
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) getParent();
    Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent: parent enabled: " + parent.isEnabled());
}
```